# Como recebo parâmetros de uma rota num controller em Typescript?

Tags: javascript, api, typescript, express.js

Tenho o simples `routes.ts`:

```
import { Router } from 'express'
import UserController from './controllers/UserController';

const routes = Router();

routes.get('/:User', UserController.index);

export default routes;
```

E então, no meu Controller `UserController`:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'api.exemplo.privada'
});


export default {
    async index(Req: Request, Res: Response, User: String) {
        api
            .get('/' + User)
            .then((ApiResponse) => {
                return Res.send(ApiResponse.data)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            });
    }
};
```

Quando passo o User como parâmetro no Controller, eu recebo o seguinte erro

```
  A última sobrecarga gerou o seguinte erro.
    O argumento do tipo '(Req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, Res: Response<any, Record<string, any>>, User: String) => Promise<...>' não é atribuível ao parâmetro do tipo 'Application'.
      O tipo '(Req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, Res: Response<any, Record<string, any>>, User: String) => Promise<...>' não tem as propriedades a seguir do tipo 'Application': init, defaultConfiguration, engine, set e mais 61.ts(2769)"
```

E é isto que não entendo, pois se eu passar somente o User como parâmetro, desta forma, dando um Console, o Controller o recebe normalmente. **Tudo roda ok!**:

```
export default {
    async index(User: String) {
       console.log(User)
    }
};
```

Assim como, quando passo somente a Request e Response do Express, com a API dando Get direto (sem o parâmetro User), **também roda ok!** (?):

```
export default {
    async index(Req: Request, Res: Response) {
        api
            .get('/UserUmExemplo')
            .then((ApiResponse) => {
                return Res.send(ApiResponse.data)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            });
    }
};
```

Alguém pode me explicar por que não consigo usar os parâmetros do Express + da rota ao mesmo tempo?

No caso, `(async index(Req: Request, Res: Response, User: String))`.

Comment: Porque o terceiro parâmetro tem que ser do tipo `NextFunction `

Comment: Então eu passo como Null, e o User passo como quarto?

Comment: Não. Se vc analisar o tipo, verá que não aceita nenhuma string. E não deu pra entender o porquê desse User. Porque não extrai via `req.params.User`

Comment: De fato, faz mais sentido, mas minha dúvida era pertinente aos parâmetros mesmo, obrigado por explicar amigo, vou procurar sobre `NextFunction `. Caí de paraquedas no TypeScript hoje.